# Unwanted white space in template of express app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to create an edit template in my express app, and I want already saved Date in my input box. But when I tried like this, a long white space is coming before and after the date.
When I inspected the HTML it was like

`value="                            Sat Sep 18 1999                                       "`

```
    <input
         type="text"
         name="student[dateOfBirth]"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="Date Of Birth"
         onfocus="(this.type='date')"
         onblur="(this.type='text')"
         min="2015-01-01"
         max="2020-12-01"
         value="<%if(student.dateOfBirth){%>
                  <%=student.dateOfBirth.toDateString()%>
                <%}%>"
    >
```

Anyone please help me to get rid of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
value="<%if(student.dateOfBirth){%>
                  <%=student.dateOfBirth.toDateString()%>
                <%}%>"
```

to

```
value="<%= student.dateOfBirth ? student.dateOfBirth.toDateString() : '' %>"
```